# How to send unicast packet to neighbour in Contiki-NG?

Tags: ipv6, contiki, contiki-ng

Is it possible in Contiki-NG to send a custom packet from a udp-client node to a neighbour using link address from neighbor cache? 
I am looking a way to avoid sending icmpv6 packet because it is going up to the root and then root sends it to destination. I saw that Contiki enables mesh topology so it should be possible to send a packet directly to neighbor without forwarding packet to parent.
I will appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPv6 has-so called link-local addresses. These are addresses with the prefix `fe80::/64`. If you want to send a packet bypassing routing then you should use these addresses. For example, if you have network with a prefix `fd00::/64` and neighbor with global IPv6 address `fd00::201:1:1:1`, then send a packet to `fe80::201:1:1:1` to reach that neighbor directly.

A side note related to "Contiki enables mesh topology" - if you're using RPL Lite or RPL Classic with non-storing mode, all routed packets will go through the root in any case, as the network nodes don't add routes to parents/children to their routing tables in this mode. Enable the storing mode to achieve direct peer-to-peer packet exchange using routing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with copying link-local address as an ipaddress and used uip_icmp6_send but seems that goes through root again. Which function should I use to send with link-local address?

Comment: @phrick How do you send it? fe80::/64 addresses should not be routed.

Comment: Ok I changed just the first bytes to match fe80 and now are sent correctly.Thanks a lot!